# parameters of jstree create_node

Tags: javascript, jstree

Could you please give me the list of parameters of this function and an example of usage

```
$('#treepanel').jstree("create_node");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

IMHO jsTree is powerful, but documentation could be improved.

The create_node function is documented [here](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=create_node(%5Bpar,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded%5D).

Be careful not interpreting the [] as a literal.  They are just to indicate that the parameters are optional.

This works for jsTree version "pre 1.0 fixed":

```
var position = 'inside';
var parent = $('#your-tree').jstree('get_selected');
var newNode = { state: "open", data: "New nooooode!" };
$('#your-tree').jstree(
    "create_node", parent, position, newNode, false, false);
```

---

JSTree 3.3.5

From their docs "create_node" functionality has inverted args 'newNode' and 'position'

```
 $('#your-tree').jstree("create_node", parent, newNode, position, false, false);
```

https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=create_node([par,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded])

Answer (score 19):

More recently, for version 3+:

```
var parent = '#';
var node = { id:123,text:"Hello world"};
$('#yourtree').jstree('create_node', parent, node, 'last');
```

Alternative syntax that seems to be working:

```
$('#yourtree').jstree().create_node(parent, node, 'last');
```

[See documentation](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=create_node([obj,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded]))

Comment: if create_node keeps returning false for you, try setting core.check_callback to true.

Comment: @bublik42: Thank you so much, I wasted an hour with jstree's hellishly frustrating documentation before reading your comment!

Comment: Is there a way to bind additional data with the newNode? I tried

    "var node = {id:123, data: {'attr1': 'val1', 'attr2': 'val2'}, text: 'myText'}"

But it doesn't work!