# programmatically add Node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am trying to add a new node in `jstree` programmatically on button click, as well as on `contextmenu` create click, but there is some issue.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/221/) is the link of fiddle.

```
<div id="jstree">
  </div>
<button id="sam">create node</button>
```

Comment: You redacted this wrong ;)

Comment: Could you be more specific on what error(s) you are receiving?

Comment: No any error getting, even console and alert is working fine, but the problem is new node is not getting added.

Comment: take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871698/parameters-of-jstree-create-node I suspect that you passing null as the parent node is the issue.

Answer (score 13):

Here is your fiddle, fixed to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/223/

You were calling `create_node` with an array, which was wrong, also the string value `'null'` was not the correct way to create a root node - use the special string value `'#'` (in later versions `null` works too, but not as a string).

You might consider upgrading the jstree version - your fiddle was using a very early beta. Also keep in mind jstree itself does not require Angular.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This code works great if you only add one node. However, if you are adding further nodes, you create them with duplicate IDs. Therefore, only the first created node is selectable. You can generate IDs with  consecutive numbers to solve this problem.